# CLI "dotnet ef" is not working for a brand new dotnet core web project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Command line error upon running `dotnet ef`:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)

---

```
Product Information:
 Version: 1.0.0-preview2-003156`
Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.14393
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
```

I am using Visual Studio Code as my IDE rather than vs-community/other.

Repro steps:

- create a new dotnet web project `dotnet new -t web`
- restore `dotnet restore`
- try to make a migration (or just see if entity framework is available in the CLI: `dotnet ef`
- error appears

Tried

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
```

as well as

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
```

. Both do not work

Comment: Why are you using project.json format still? Update your sdk.

Comment: @Mardoxx - Upgraded to dotnet core 1.1 to bypass the issue. 

So I didn't solve the error but this is no longer an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Hi do you have this on your dependencies?

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
```

Comment: Weird, I swear I responded to this last week. Yes, I had `Tools` as a dependency but no avail. I ended up upgrading to core 1.1 and .csproj files have been much better to me.

Comment: Yup, hmmmm... everything is fine now?